# NavBar menu list does not appear after the first click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, menu, toggle

I have this code that toggle a menu on mobile devices, work just fine...
When I click just one time at the menu, he work's nice, with the blur effect and all your functions... But if I click more than one time in the icon menu, he stop to show my menu-list, my `navbarr__menu` class...

I add a function to when the user click outside (in the `.main` class) of the `navbarr__menu` class, the menu close... (work's too)

```
             <ul class="navbarr__menu">
                <li class="navbarr__item">
                    <a href="#me" class="navbarr__links"><span>01.&nbsp;</span>About me </a>
                </li>
                <li class="navbarr__item">
                    <a href="#work" class="navbarr__links"><span>02.&nbsp;</span>Projects</a>
                </li>
                <li class="navbarr__item">
                    <a href="#contact" class="navbarr__links"><span>03.&nbsp;</span>Contact </a>
                </li>
                <li class="navbarr__item">
                    <a href="#resume" class="navbarr__links"><button type="button" id="resumeID" class="resume-btn" onclick="openResume()">Resume</button></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

The javaScript is working well, but I keep having this issue when i click for the second time at the menu icon...

```
    let menu = document.querySelector('#mobile-menu');
    let menuLinks = document.querySelector(".navbarr__menu");
    menu.addEventListener('click', function(){
        if(menu.classList.toggle('is-active')){
          $("section").addClass("main-blur");
          $('.main').click(function() {
            //Hide the menus if visible
            console.log("Entrei");
            $(".navbarr__menu").hide();
            $("section").removeClass("main-blur");
            $("#mobile-menu").removeClass("is-active");
            
          }),
          $('.main').click(function(event){
            event.stopPropagation();
            console.log("Sai");
            
        });          
        } else {
          $("section").removeClass("main-blur");
        }
        menuLinks.classList.toggle('active');
    }),
```

Does anyone **know why is this happening?** and how to **fix it??**

Comment: That's an odd mixture of jQuery and native JS. Why not stick with one or the other?

Comment: Your code has multiple problems and appears to be incomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the if statement maybe try

if(menu.classList.contains('is-active'))

Comment: Please use those Code Snippet tags to make you code shown as code

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).